# Creating, assigning roles to users and loading menu based on roles assigned

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I want to creates roles for the registered application in Azure Active Directory and load the menu depending on the roles assigned to the user.

I have done this in my previous project where there is no Identity provider, Security service provider or there is no OIDC. The process we followed as below

- Creating user from User creation screen
- Creating roles from Roles creation screen and assign Menu Items to the roles
- Assign roles to user from User Role Assignment screen
- Loading Menu Items depending on the user roles

  All this data is stored in RDBMS

  I want to do all the above operation from application using Azure Active Directory. I have searched in google. All examples are showing like going to azure portal and doing all manually. But I want to do this from application. 

  1) Load the user from Azure Active Directory into the application when admin logs in.

  2) Creating roles for the registered application in Azure Active Directory and assign Menu Items to the roles

  3) Assign roles to the users

Note: We are using Azure Active Directory B2B and SSO application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure AD B2C, you can achieve this in  a different manner.Before you even start i would explain bit about User role and Group in Azure AD B2C.

User role in AD B2C is way of B2C telling you that what permission you have inside Azure AD. To implement you problem statement , Though you can utilize Group member ship.

To implement this kind of behavior, all you have to do is create your application specific group and assign user's in them.

Once group creation and user mapping is done then you can write code to get user member ship from you application , here is a sample code for getting [group member ship.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/60e5685dc72a6199f683ce6d2f0d8ed2263357c2/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/GroupsController.cs) which you can store at your client application.

I am afraid that there is no direct way to add Group member ship in you claims, here is supporting doc for:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b

But in a nutshell , Role base menu creation implementation logic, you have to write at the client side only by accessing session storage item.

https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for giving valuable information. So I will create users, groups, add users to groups from  dotnet core c#. For menu items, I will maintain menu items based on groups in our database. And when user logs in, I will retrieve groups from token and send the menu items to front end. Is this correct? I am having one doubt storing menu items in session storage will be security issue as user can tamper the session storage. The best thing when ever user refresh the application we have to fetch menu items from back end.

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if it helped as it will help other who have the same ask.